# PHP: How to order 3 arrays in 1 array while reordering the array

Tags: php, arrays, transpose

I need to merge 3 arrays into 1, while ordering the new array in a way that the first entry of the second array follows the first entry of the first array.

Example:

```
$array1 = array(dog, cat, mouse);
$array2 = array(table, chair, couch);
$array3 = array(car, bike, bus);
```

These arrays should result in the following array:

```
$resultarray = array(dog, table, car, cat, chair, bike, mouse, couch, bus);
```

Many thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 8):

All you need is :

```
$resultarray = array();
foreach(array_map(null, $array1, $array2, $array3) as $set) {
    $resultarray = array_merge($resultarray, $set);
}
print_r($resultarray);
```

[Output](http://eval.in/31250)

```
Array
(
    [0] => dog
    [1] => table
    [2] => car
    [3] => cat
    [4] => chair
    [5] => bike
    [6] => mouse
    [7] => couch
    [8] => bus
)
```

[See Live DEMO](http://eval.in/31250)

Or Simple one line solution - [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map(null, $array1, $array2, $array3));
```

[One Line DEMO](http://eval.in/31256)

Comment: `call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map(null, $array1, $array2, $array3))` :-3

Comment: Very elegant ! A double loop would have done it if not for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
Can I also use your solution when I'm using a multidimensional array:

$array = array(array(dog, cat, mouse),array(table, chair, couch),array(car, bike, bus));

Comment: That a different case  depends on you desired output and existing multidimensional  array structure

Comment: @TeusLouwerens You only need to "spread" the multidimensional array with `...` (splat operator).    `array_merge(...array_map(null, ...$multi))`

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
$array1 = array('dog', 'cat', 'mouse');
$array2 = array('table', 'chair', 'couch');
$array3 = array('car', 'bike', 'bus');

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', call_user_func_array('array_map', array(null,$array1,$array2,$array3)));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

**EDIT** : As per **deceze** comment :

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map(null,$array1,$array2,$array3));
```

Inner `call_user_func_array` is removed.

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => dog
    [1] => table
    [2] => car
    [3] => cat
    [4] => chair
    [5] => bike
    [6] => mouse
    [7] => couch
    [8] => bus
)
```

Comment: That inner `call_user_func_array` is superfluous.

Comment: @deceze : That was just to transpose the array

Comment: ?? Could easily be written as `array_map(null,$array1,$array2,$array3)` for the same effect.

Comment: @deceze : ohhh..yeahh..thanks for the information, I will add that too in my anwser :)

Answer (score 1):

*Just another one line solution:*

```
$result = array_reduce(array_map(null, $array1, $array2, $array3), 'array_merge', array());
```